# Blocking javascript events on h:outputText where escape=true

Tags: javascript, jquery

I work for a website which is sort of a social network, and people can send messages to anyone. There was a guy who sent a

> `<script>alert('bah');</script>`

And it created a javascript:alert..

How can I prevent this to happen?

> I've made a method that gets the text typed and if it's typed < it
>   transforms into `"&#60;"` and > to `"&#62;"`

But even doing this, the code above still worked. Is there anything else that I could do to prevent it to happen again?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to simply disable the use of scripts via targeting and filtering the entire script tag.

Comment: Would you please be more specific?

Comment: you could process and remove <script></script> from the messages sent when someone sends a message.

Comment: i see. i haven't thought about it, thanks! What about javascript inside html code? I just keep on doing what i've been doing all this time?

Comment: I think all you need is to sanitize the user inputs by looking for messages that could execute scripts. Allowing users to send messages that contain executable scripts is inherently dangerous and can allow for possibly malicious messages.